# Optimizing requests to the File System via PHP

Tags: php, optimization, server, filesystems, backend

**Here is 2 methods:**

1.⠀I'm storing some numbers via "php" inside a file, it's done by `file_put_contents()`, each number has a separator to determine which one is which. Sometimes I read the file so to know if the required number is inside, for that I use simple `strpos()` after `file_get_contents()`. And of course sometimes I need to delete a particular number from the file, to do so firstly I `file_get_contents()`, after I use a combination of `strpos()` + `substr()` and for the final step `file_put_contents()`

2.⠀I'm storing some numbers via "php" as a filename (file) in a folder, for that I use `file_put_contents()`. And when I need to check one I just use `file_exists()`, and when I need to delete one I `unlink()`

**What I want:**

I would like to understand which method is a better solution. I guess it does not much matter when we're talking about a couple of requests (executions), but I want it be universal: can normally work with low load and high load. I cannot simulate a multi-request situation in order to see if there will be a problem. I personally think that the first method is good because it just one file. But exactly here are my concerns about normal processing on high load. I mean I have no idea how `file_put_contents()` will handle multiple requests at the same time (I have already read all the links on this matter that you can even show me in the comments!). Yes, I'm aware that this function provides the `LOCK_EX` flag, but still, I have read that this may not work as expected, at least on some OS. The second method I like a lot, cuz you can simple check if there's the number you need, cuz you can simple delete the file/number without concerns that some parallel request will block it, I mean that everything can be done just with 3 functions. But will it work normally if there will be some 100 thousands files/numbers stored, and if more, that's what I think about.

About the numbers, it's just a random number, let it be 32 or 64 characters length. I do not need to do nothing more, just check if certain number exist, just delete it if I don't need it anymore.

So, what do you think, maybe someone has an experience on similar task, which method do you think is better, or maybe you know another one? Everything must work nicely on any OS, under low and high load. I'm gratefully appreciate every opinion!

**UPDATE:**

Okay, I believe I wont get more answers, so I'd like to clarify something. Firstly, I'm a bit disappointed, about how things are working here. Because I was expecting talks about FileSystem (that's in the title!) and no one (almost) did that. I guess this is not a place for such a question, where you can discuss something. Secondly, I actually know what is a "Database" and what it was designed for. Still, I already using the 1 and 2 method for different purposes. FileSystem exists for something, isn't it??? I want to get rid of the 1 method and combine it with the second. I can't get rid of the second method, cuz it's a part of whole system, this "number", file/number of 2 method, about which I was talking, it's in fact a personal special script for logged user. And nope, it should be this way, it can't be one script for all users. I can't draw in your mind here how the full system work and why, that would not be right. I asked a simple question, and you all telling me that access data base via PHP it's a lot much faster than just do this `file_exists()`, nothing more. Ok, then! And yes, I didn't told you all this before, so I'm bad, you're good, that's anyway! And nope, I'm not taking this personally, as I said, ok then!

Comment: Are you just testing that a number exists, or is there more information associated with it.  Also what is the potential range - or can it be any number?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using databases, or an in memory cache like redis or something?

Comment: _"So, what do you think"_ - that databases exist. End of discussion :-p

Comment: I'm not so sure a filesystem is very efficient for this kind of task but typically I would imagine method 1 to be slower if the file gets big. I would personnally use a database such as MySQL or SQLite to do that as you can have an index which will be fast to search for the number and also delete it. If you cannot do that then do a mix of solution 1 and 2 : create a folder for each groups of numbers, typically 0-1000, 1001-2000, etc and then a file to store them. You'll minimize the number of files and have a fixed size to minimize the search.

Comment: @nigel-ren, it's just a random number, let it be 32 or 64 characters length. I do not need to do nothing more, just check if certain number exist, just delete it if I don't need it anymore.

Comment: @CBroe First at all I didn't asked about databases, read the title please and the context. Secondly, okay, as I said I appreciate opinions, but can you explain something, for example as  Patrick Janser did? :P

Comment: There is not much to explain. Databases were _made_ for this, they handle locking/concurrent access for you already, and they can handle high request volumes.

Comment: Patrick Janser Okay, I see, everyone is about databases. But what about preparing requests to access database in order to read some data. I mean, obviously, I can't allow anyone, without checking, access database (or filesystem) especially delete something, and after every "get the number from MySql", yeah I can check num_rows, but maybe need to do mysqli_fetch_row() or something like that. Isn't it a lot to process on "PHP" side?

Comment: Typical Stackoverflow, yeah just up vote yourself, and down vote me, because I'm using File System instead of Databases as you and because you don't know how to answer this "How to optimize requests to the File System via PHP?". You answer is simple: DON'T, use databases LoL!!!

Comment: The answer is that it's very hard to do this, and it would a LOT easier to do it using database. You want the best way to do this task? Answer: Use a database. Some questions are an XY problem and don't need a direct answer, because no-one would attempt this once they understand that they can use a database instead. Don't take it personally, that's just the fact of the matter. Besides, you've received _one_ downvote. If there was such a big movement against your question, it would have been downvoted 10 times that.

Comment: `But what about preparing requests to access database in order to read some data`...what about them? You just write a SQL query and send it. The SQL engine will do most of the heavy lifting of actually processing the query. All PHP has to do is send it, and read the results. It's unclear what your concern would be. mysqli_fetch_row isn't a performance killer, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: @ADyson Now I see, constructive response, thanks for explanations